# TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType) in output

Tags: python, strerror

```
class Point4D(object):
    def __init__(self,w, x, y, z):
        self.w = w
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

    def __str__(self):
        print('{}, {}, {}, {}'.format(self.w, self.x, self.y, self.z))

my_4d_point = Point4D(1, 2, 3, 1)
print(my_4d_point)
```

I get the output 1 2 3 1 , but i keep getting the error
 `TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType) in line 12.` Why?

Comment: `__str__` is expected to return a string.

Comment: Because **your `__str__` function returnes `None`**.

Answer (score 2):

`__str__` is supposed to return a string. Your function currently returns `None`. Printing a string is not returning the string.

You're almost there. Change it to the following:

```
    def __str__(self):
        return '{}, {}, {}, {}'.format(self.w, self.x, self.y, self.z)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `return`. The error is because you print, but return nothing.

```py
def __str__(self):
        return('{}, {}, {}, {}'.format(self.w, self.x, self.y, self.z))
```

Answer (score 0):

method _*str_* should **return** (not print) string repesentration of object.

Answer (score -1):

you have to use the `return` statement instead of `print` because the `__str__` function is supposed to return a `string`

```
class Point4D():
    def __init__(self,w, x, y, z):
        self.w = w
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

    def __str__(self):
        return('{}, {}, {}, {}'.format(self.w, self.x, self.y, self.z))

my_4d_point = Point4D(1, 2, 3, 1)
print(my_4d_point)
```

output:

```
1, 2, 3, 1
```